# Process data: error: execution of DDL failed

Tags: ssis, ssas, ddl, cube, sql-agent-job

I have encountered an issue while executing a SSAS cube tabular in SSIS through SQL Server Agent. The error message received is: "Process data: error: execution of DDL failed." I have attempted to address this by creating a proxy and granting the necessary permissions to the user, but unfortunately, the issue persists. Could you please assist me in finding a solution?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If the **error messages** do not clearly state the problem, I recommend filtering the **warning messages**. It worked for me.